# Convert between TProtocols

Tags: java, thrift, thrift-protocol

I'd like to convert from TBinaryProtocol to TSimpleJSONProtocol, so that I can display a recorded stream of binary thrift requests in a more human-readable fashion.  I'm particularly interested in the service requests in the stream, so using the TDeserializer isn't an option (I'm also hoping to keep the code generic wrt the particular Thrift service/objects being used.

Is there a way to directly convert the TBinaryProtocol object to TSimpleJSONProtocol without the intermediate step of constructing a Thrift object?

Answer (score 0):

A protocol has absolutely nothing to do with the data. Your question is like asking, can I convert the HTTP protocol to an FTP protocol without doing any kind of decoding. I seriously doubt it, although I've been wrong before.

It would be far easier to simply use the JSON protocol all the way through. It's thrift -- changing that is literally a one-liner. The binary protocol is notoriously difficult to debug, switch to something else for your own sanity. Switch back to binary when everything seems to be working.